# Curl in flitter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, curl, https

Please I would really appreciate if anyone can explain how to use the below code in flitter.

curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=Username&password=Password" 
-H "Authorization: Basic Base64(consumer-key:consumer-secret)" 
https://devesb.elicia.systems:8263/token

The above cURL command shows how to generate an access token using the Password Grant type.

That was what they said, Then I was given this:

```
curl -k -X POST "https://devesb.vfdbank.systems:8263/vfd-wallet/1.1/wallet2/onboarding?wallet-credentials=wallet-credentials" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer c9b84e30-e59a-3789-b6d1-3595552dfb23" -d "{ \"username\": \"Username used to signup\", \"walletName\": \"Company/Wallet name\", \"webhookUrl\": \"Inward notifications Webhook\", \"shortName\": \"Wallet short name (4 Characters)\", \"implementation\": \"POOL or 1-1\"}"
```

was also given a consumer key and consumer secret key. Could you please help me structure the above curl (The one I was given) and tell me where to add the consumer and secret keys. Have been on this for weeks now and I would be so very grateful if you could help me out on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your issue isn't that you need Dart/Flutter code. You need to learn how curl commands are structured and, possibly, how HTTP requests are formed in general. Once you know that, any one of dozens of tutorials online will tell you how to make an HTTP request in Dart.

Comment: I have update my question. I was given a consumer key and consumer secret key with a curl, which I would want to run on my flutter app. Knowing how to structure curl would be very nice. So what am pleading for is if I could be assisted in structuring the curl for flutter and where to add the consumer keys. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

Here is a more or less straightforward translation of your code:

```dart
// Required for base64encode and utf8 encoding
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void forExample() async {
  final testUsername = 'username';
  final testPassword = 'password';

  final uri = Uri.parse('https://devesb.elicia.systems:8263/token');

  final token = base64Encode(utf8.encode('$testUsername:$testPassword'));

  final response = await http.post(
    uri,
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': 'Basic $token',
    },
    body: {
      'grant_type': 'password',
      'username': testUsername,
      'password': testPassword,
    },
  );

  print(response.body);
}
```

Note: In the above code, the request body will be automatically encoded as x-www-form-urlencoded, as in your curl request.

Comment: You appear to have overloaded `testUsername` in both the query and the auth header. From the curl it seems that the auth header should be formed from the consumer key and secret.

Comment: Wow am so very grateful for the quick response and time. I was given a consumer and secret keys and also a token.